# Relative Entropy function in R

Tags: r, function, vector

I want to construct a function that calculates the relative entropy between two discrete probability distributions.

The following attempt works:

```
    H <- function(p1, p2, p3 = 1 - p1 - p2, q1, q2, q3 = 1 - q1 - q2) {
      p <- c(p1, p2, p3)
      q <- c(q1, q2, q3)
      return(sum(log(p^p) - log(q^p)))
}
```

but I wanted to simplify it so that the arguments were just the vector:

```
D<-function(x,y){
  return(sum(log(x^x)-log(y^x)))
}
```

which doesn't work. What is the problem here? Can you not define functions with inputs that are vectors?

Example:

```
a<-c(0.2,0.5,0.3)
b<-c(0.4,0.4,0.2)
```

then

```
    H(0.2,0.5,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.2) 
 0.094
```

which is correct, but:

```
D(a,b)
Inf
```

which is not correct

Comment: Please show an example of data. And which error message do you get?

Comment: I don't understand the result of your `D(a,b)`. I tried your definition of `D` and the data for `a` and `b` and `D(a,b)` gave: `[1] 0.09458187`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
p1 <- 1
p2 <- 2
q1 <- 4
q2 <- 5

H <- function(p1, p2, q1, q2){
  p3 <- 1 - p1 - p2
  q3 <- 1 - q1 - q2
  p <- c(p1, p2, p3)
  q <- c(q1, q2, q3)
  return(sum(log(p^p) - log(q^p)))
}
H(p1, p2, q1, q2)
# [1] -0.4462871

x <- c(p1, p2, 1 - p1 - p2)
y <- c(q1, q2, 1 - q1 - q2)

D <- function(x, y){
  return(sum(log(x^x)-log(y^x)))
}
D(x, y)
# [1] -0.4462871
```

Comment: thanks, so just to clarify I need to define the form of my arguments before defining the function? why does D work only after specifying the form of x,y?

Comment: `D(c(p1, p2, 1 - p1 - p2), c(q1, q2, 1 - q1 - q2))` also works.